# Загрузка картинки

Tags: java, linux, изображения, rest

Не могу загрузить картинку в директорию на linux на лету.
Есть URL которая принимает на вход bitmap с формочки, декодирует и сохраняет ввиде картинки JPEG формата.

```
@Path("/userprofile")
@Produces(value={MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public class UserAvatar {

@POST
@Path("/{uuid}")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
public String uploadAvatar(@PathParam("uuid") String uuid, @FormParam("image") String data){
        JSONObject js = new JSONObject();
        AvatarService.updateAvatar(uuid, data);
        js.put("uploadstatus",true);
        return js.toString();
}
}
```

Собственно сам метод updateAvatar

```
final static String folderName = "/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT/images";
   public static void updateAvatar(String uuid, String data){
    String avatarURI;
    try{
        BASE64Decoder base64Decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
        byte[] base64 = base64Decoder.decodeBuffer(data);
        ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(base64);
        avatarURI = folderName+"/"+uuid+".jpeg";
        try{
            BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(bis);
            ImageIO.write(image, "jpeg", new File("photo.jpeg"));
        }catch (FileNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Стек ошибок :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(ImageIO.java:1538)
Tripod.Service.AvatarService.updateAvatar(AvatarService.java:25)
Tripod.Resources.UserAvatar.uploadAvatar(UserAvatar.java:18)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:144)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:161)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:205)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:309)
org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:292)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1139)
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:460)
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:386)
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:334)
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:221)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Если изменить folderName на любой другой в windows , то все прекрастно работает , картинка сохраняется и возвращаеться json

Comment: С правами на запись у пользователя, от которого работает сервер все хорошо?

Comment: Судя по стеку вы после строчки `BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(bis);` получили null. Возможно что-то не так с кодировкой\раскодировкой изображения. Проверьте первые 2 байта из `byte[] base64` они должны быть FF D8 для jpeg.
И еще вы всегда сохраняете в файл с именем "photo.jpeg", хотя в коде предусмотрен путь и uuid для файла.

Comment: @zRrr Да , права на запись/чтение файлов в директории есть.

Comment: @Alexandr . То что я получил null это я понимаю . Байты посмотрю , а по-поводу имени ... да , тут я кинул немного старую версию , но это тут неважно ибо я тестил неоднократно (с другими директориями и разрешениями ) , а в итоге на винде все ок , а на linux null.

Comment: А какая Java у вас на линуксе? Если OpenJDK то может там нет родного декодера jpeg? Да и попробуйте какими-нибудь другими средствами сохранить сразу `byte[] base64`, без предварительной попытки обработать это как изображение.